# linq query delay result for large amount of data

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, query-performance

I have query where i am getting 5 mins to execute the below query (total records 40k)

```
var assetAssociatedEvents = (from mainNodes in projectNodes
     select new OrgManagementEvent
     {
         OrgAssetsAssociatedEvent = new OrgAssetsAssociatedEvent
         {
             CustomerUID = Guid.Parse(CustomerUID),
             OrgUid = Guid.Parse(mainNodes.NodeObjectUID),

             AssociatedAssetUids = (from assets in customerAssets
                                    join assetNodes in assetNodeObjects
                                    on assets.AssetID equals assetNodes.fk_AssetID
                                    where assetNodes.fk_NodeObjectID == mainNodes.NodeObjectID
                                    select assets.AssetUID).Distinct().ToList().ConvertAll(Guid.Parse).ToArray(),
             Timestamp = timeStampDetail
         }
     }).ToList();
```

can you please correct me if any where i am doing wrong to improve performance.

Comment: Do you really need it in a list? Could you just iterate through as each item arrived?

Answer (score 0):

Is it neccessary for you to apply all this conversions? When you call ToList() you are iterating all through the dataset, when calling ConverAll you are doing it again and then you call ToArray to the same effect. Maybe you can consider using just the linq part and then operate with the result of the linq query

```
    (from assets in customerAssets join assetNodes in assetNodeObjects on assets.AssetID equals assetNodes.fk_AssetID where assetNodes.fk_NodeObjectID ==  mainNodes.NodeObjectID select assets.AssetUID)
```

I think that that alone could improve greatly the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split your query. Something like that should improve the performance:

```
var allAssetUids = (from assets in customerAssets
                    join assetNodes in assetNodeObjects
                    on assets.AssetID equals assetNodes.fk_AssetID                                 
                    select assets.AssetUID)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList()
                    .ConvertAll(Guid.Parse);
```

And afterwards do

```
var assetAssociatedEvents = (from mainNodes in projectNodes
 select new OrgManagementEvent
 {
     OrgAssetsAssociatedEvent = new OrgAssetsAssociatedEvent
     {
         CustomerUID = Guid.Parse(CustomerUID),
         OrgUid = Guid.Parse(mainNodes.NodeObjectUID),    
         Timestamp = timeStampDetail
     }
 }).ToList();
```

In the en iterate over your events like

```
foreach(var associatedEvent in assetAssociatedEvents){
    AssociatedAssetUids = allAssetUids.Where(p => p == associatedEvent.NodeObjectID).ToArray();
}
```